# UWP BackgroundTask on App update

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, background-task

I have a short question, if i update my App, which contains a BackgroundTask, do i need to unregister and re-register the task after the update? I have experienced that the BackgroundTask does not work anymore after an Update on some user's devices and the user had to disable and enable it again. I saw in the msdn documentation a "ServicingComplete" BackgroundTask, which should be launched after an App update, so is it the right way, to re-register my main BackgroundTask in there? Or what is the favorite way to make a simple BackgroundTask work to 100% after an App update?

Comment: How you register your background task? In which situation the user register your background task in your app? Or your background need always register once the app is installed.

Comment: I register the BackgroundTask manually in my App with a Button. But when i submit an update for the App, then on some user's devices the BackgroundTask does not work anymore, as soon the App update is installed. After press the Button to register the BackgroundTask inside the App, the BackgroundTask is working again. But this is only on a few devices the case. So my question is, how to handle that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is yes. If your app has updated, you need to

- Unregister your background task
- Call `BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();`
- Call `BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();`
- Register your task again

In my own app I stash the latest version number in the local settings so that I can detect this.

Comment: Ok but is this possible to do from the ServicingComplete Task or do you re-register it on App launch? Is RemoveAccess() everytime necessary?

Comment: I had this problem too, just tried this and it is indeed the RemoveAccess hat makes the difference. Without it my (InProcess) task just didn't ran, without any error messages.

Comment: @andy: I register (if necessary) on app startup. In your case, where registering the background task is a user-initiated thing, you could just check on startup whether the task was already registered. If not, do nothing; otherwise check for app update and go through the steps I listed. I haven't used the ServicingComplete background task myself, so I hesitate to give any advice -- it might well be a viable option.

Comment: Ok i see, but my Problem is, that the BackgroundTask should work after an Ap update without to Launch the App to re-register the BackgroundTask.

Comment: Then I suggest you look at ServicingComplete. It sure _looks_ like it should be the right thing, but I don't have any practical experience with it.

Comment: I looked at the ServicingComplete BackgroundTask, but i didn't found any real example on how to re-register BackgroundTasks the right way. As you said, the RemoveAccess() and the RequestAccessAsync() is necessary, i tought that RequestAccessAsync() is only callable from the foreground App (UI)?

Comment: That was necessary in Win 8/8.1. It is not necessary in Win10.

Comment: You mean necessary to call it on the foreground App?

Comment: You can call it from the background in Win10.

Comment: It is working now inside the ServicingComplete BackgroundTask, as it turns out, it was the missing BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess(). So thank you very much for your help!